# Salto de línea CSS desacomoda los input

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando crear un formulario, y después de cada `<label>` hay un `<br>` para que se baje el input, el problema es que cuando hay dos o más `<label>` en el mismo div que les da el CSS se desacomoda.

Esto es cómo lo tengo si no le doy salto de línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así queda cuando pongo el `<br>` después de la etiqueta de `<label>`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el CSS dónde están encerrados

```
.grupoVisual{
  border: solid #ccc 0.5px;
  padding: 0.5%;
  border-style: dotted solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Este es el HTML

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Lista de apartados</legend>
    <div class="grupoVisual">
      <label>Tipo Fecha:</label><br>
      <div class="tooltip">
        <select class="likeDhx">
        <option value="1" selected>Alta</option>
        </select>
        <div class="tooltiptext">Indica en que campo de fecha se hará la búsqueda</div>
      </div>


      <div class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" class="cal likeDhx" <?php echo "value='".date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '-7 day')). "'"; ?>>
        <span class="tooltiptext">Indica la fecha en donde terminará la búsqueda</span>
      </div>

      <div class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" class="cal likeDhx" <?php echo "value='".date( "Y-m-d"). "'"; ?>>
        <span class="tooltiptext">Indica la fecha en donde terminará la búsqueda</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grupoVisual">
      <label for="tienda_redencion">Tienda Redención:</label><br>
      <div class="tooltip">
        <select>
        <option value="0" checked="1">Global</option>
        </select>
        <div class="tooltiptext">Indica la tienda en donde el cliente recogerá el producto</div>
      </div>




      <label for="categoria">Categoria:</label>
      <div class="tooltip">
        <select>
        <option value="0" checked="1">Global</option>
        </select>
        <div class="tooltiptext">Indica la categoría del producto a buscar</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="grupoVisual">
      <label>Estatus Apartado:</label><br>
      <div class="tooltip">
        <select>
        <option value="99" checked="1">Global</option>
        </select>
        <div class="tooltiptext">Indica el estatus del producto que estas buscando</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <button type="button" class="consulta_boton">Consultar</button>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Sugerencias para que el input de Categoría no se baje de favor?

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el código del formulario?

Comment: Listo @CarlosMuñoz

Comment: El CSS que has colocado no es suficiente para reproducir el problema, te sugiero que coloques todo lo relevante

Answer (score 0):

bueno en muchos casos lo que he hecho para que no suceda esto es colocar el select dentro del label para que así quede "cubierto" por el mismo label.

```
<label>Categoria: <br/><select name="categoria" > .... </select></label>
```

O intenta crear nuevos div en cada uno de los componentes asi separas por grupo y no se genera mezcla. y revisar los margin para que no genere espacios innecesarios

Comment: No funcionó u_u

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob revisa esa edición para ver si así te funciona.

Comment: Nada, sigue igual

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo te podria sugerir es que se div tenga otros dos divs donde a cada uno le des la proporcion que quieres del padre supongamos que div grupoVisual contendra a dos cajitas mas pequeñas asifnandole a una no se un 60% del tamaño total de grupo visual y la otra el 40% mas o menos quedaria asi de forma rapida:

```
<div class="grupoVisual">
<div style="width:60%;">
    <label for="tienda_redencion">Tienda Redención:</label><br>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <select>
                <option value="0" checked="1">Global</option>
            </select>
            <div class="tooltiptext">Indica la tienda en donde el cliente recogerá el producto</div>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div style="width:40%">
    <label for="categoria">Categoria:</label><br>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <select>
                <option value="0" checked="1">Global</option>
            </select>
            <div class="tooltiptext">Indica la categoría del producto a buscar</div>
        </div>
</div>
```